# Should I get an internal or external tankless natural gas water heater for Norfolk Virgina?

Tags: water-heater

My house already has natural gas but the existing water heater is an electric tanked version located in the wooden laundry room addition on a brick home. December, January and February are marginal for freezing:

https://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/norfolk/virginia/united-states/usva0557

This is a two story home with a shower upstairs and downstairs.

Should I get an indoor tankless, outdoor tankless or an indoor tanked?

Should I try to support both showers from one unit or get two smaller units, one for upstairs and one for downstairs?

Tanks.

Comment: Staying with electric or switching to gas?

Comment: My working plan is to switch to natural gas since I have that coming into the home already. I'm open though.

Comment: This is really an opinion based question and off topic.

Comment: What do you have for an HVAC system already? Why are you wanting to replace the existing water heater?

Comment: I'm seeing rust in a pattern suggesting some leakage. I have natural gas heat and it has an integrated a/c unit.

Comment: @Ruminator -- a package unit, in other words, that sits outside the house, with ducts from it to the house itself?  And also: how big (in gallons) is the existing heater?

Comment: PY3G
Owner’s Manual
13 SEER
SINGLE PACKAGED AIR CONDITIONER AND
GAS FURNACE SYSTEM
WITH R ---410A REFRIGERANT
SIZES 024 ---060

Comment: @Ruminator -- how big (in gallons) is the existing water heater?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  50 gallons:  https://www.statewaterheaters.com/support/es6-52-dort/